# Webserver un-contactable when openvpn is active

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, openvpn

I have been trying constantly to get this working for a fortnight. I am about to admit defeat but I really cannot.

I have openvpn client installed on my router and have it connected to an online VPN provider. I can successfully route all traffic through the VPN and I can also successfully route only the traffic from specific IPS in my LAN over the VPN (so not all my traffic goes through the VPN).

The problem that I need to resolve is that when I am connected to the VPN I can no longer access/ping my webserver which is on a NAS attached to my LAN. I assume this is something related to iptables, routing, NAT or something. . . i have no idea after 2 weeks of reading threads and running around in circles.

```
WAN (ISP) = 94.173.xx.xx
ROUTER with OpenVPN Client = 192.168.1.1
NAS (containing Webserver) = 192.168.2.20
```

My config file is;

```
daemon
client
dev tap11
proto udp
remote openvpn.anonine.net 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo adaptive
verb 3
ca ca.crt
auth-user-pass up
status-version 2
status status

# Custom Configuration
script-security 3 system
verb 3
mute 20
ns-cert-type server 
route-noexec
route-delay 2
redirect-private
reneg-sec 0
```

iptables –nvL gives;

```
root@unknown:/# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 61 packets, 7990 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tap11  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   17   752 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
 2152  433K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   104 shlimit    tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 state NEW
    1    65 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  655 51259 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   49 15227 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:67 dpt:68

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  136  106K ACCEPT     all  --  tap11  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
15833 5468K            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           account: network/netmask: 192.168.2.0/255.255.255.0 name: lan
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
   35  2052 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
15731 5459K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    52 wanin      all  --  vlan2  *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   52  4584 wanout     all  --  *      vlan2   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  101  9026 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 886 packets, 129K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain shlimit (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    2   104            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           recent: SET name: shlimit side: source
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 name: shlimit side: source

Chain wanin (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:50025
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:50079
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:143
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        udp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:6789
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        udp dpt:6789
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:50110
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        udp dpt:22
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:51413
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:9091
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        udp dpt:9091
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:6017
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        tcp dpt:1194
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.20        udp dpt:1194
```

And;

```
root@unknown:/# ip route list
94.174.0.1 dev vlan2  scope link
178.73.204.128/25 dev tap11  proto kernel  scope link  src 178.73.204.136
192.168.2.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
94.174.0.0/22 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src 94.174.3.40
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
default via 94.174.0.1 dev vlan2
```

Can someone please please assist me. I really need to get this working and have been trying constantly for 2 weeks to resolve this. I really have given this everything I can by myself. I am willing to research etc if pushed in the correct direction – just at the moment I have been looking at it so long I don’t know what the right direction may be anymore!

Thank-you in advance. Any assistance appreciated.

C

Comment: what's in your nat table (`iptables -t nat -nvL`)?